# Node get path of the requiring parent file

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a node module and need to read a file in the same directory as the file which requires my module.

For instance, I have `app.js` and in the same folder, `template.html`.
In some unknown directory is `module.js` and `app.js` requires it.

How can I read `template.html` from `module.js`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Inside your file you will have a module global (not actually a global)
you can get the parent object using `module.parent` and the filename with `module.parent.filename` then you could extract the folder

so from from your module.js you can use `module.parent.filename.`
http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

```
p = require('path')
template = p.join(p.dirname(module.parent.filename),'template.html')
```

And if you are looking for the path of the file which was executed then you can use `require.main.filename`

Comment: It seems like module.parent.filename is set by the file that requires the module first.  If you require the module anywhere else, this value will not update from what I can tell.

Comment: `module.parent` seems to be deprecated. `require.main.filename` should give you the entry point: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_main

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname

The you can just do this from within `app.js`:

```
var path = __dirname + '/template.html';
```

Then you can send this path to your `module.js` via some function or API.

Then your module can just use this path.

Comment: That link seems to say __dirname isn't actually a global but rather local to each module.

Comment: @JacksonGariety then use ```__filename``` and do some modification.

Comment: `__filename` gives me the path to `module.js`

Comment: I want the module to handle this. I've never seen a module before that asked you to pass it your current directory.

Comment: @JacksonGariety I've never seen a module that uses the calling module's path to find other files.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a "module.js", the trick is using **module.parent.[filename](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_filename)**

I don't personally like using globals, and for certain files (like configuration or templates), managing module require stack isn't so hard.

module.parent is mapped to the parent requiring module (which could be app.js as in your example).

Combining module.parent.filename with the path module gets you a few useful things like:

```
    var path = require('path');
    var parent_path = path.dirname(module.parent.filename);
    var parent_relative = path.resolve(path.join(parent_path, '../', 'view'));
    var template = path.join(parent_path,'./views/template.html');
```

I don't like using globals for anything to do with paths, I get spagetti `../../../dir./s`